# Get correct type information after changing the position of properties on an object

Tags: typescript

I have a nested options object that gets modified by some code and shifts certain properties up one level.

I am struggling to get proper typescript support on this scenario.

```js
function createStore(options) {
  // do stuff
}

// given
const options = {
  state: {},
  modules: {
    buildings: {
      state: {},
      modules: {
        school: {
          state: {}
        },
        cafe: {
          state: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

// type definitions that aren't working
type ObjectInfer<T> = T extends { modules: infer A } ? A : T;
type Store<T> = { [P in keyof T]: ObjectInfer<T[P]> };

// process the options object recursively and move the module definitions up one level
const store = (createStore(options) as unknown) as Store<typeof options>;

console.log(store);

// output:
/* 
{
  state: {},
  buildings: {
    state: {},
    school: {
      state: {}
    },
    cafe: {
      state: {}
    }
  }
}
*/
```

I expected the store to be correctly typed as seen above however the type cast is not working as intended and still has the same structure as the options object.

Comment: I was about to say you didn't show us the code that actually moves properties around, but then I had a horrible thought: maybe you think `as Store<typeof options>` somehow does that for you? But `as` is a purely compile-time [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), not any sort of [runtime casting](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-this-incorrect-cast-throw-a-runtime-error). The type system, including any type assertions, is [erased](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) by runtime.

Comment: The createStore function actually does quite a lot of work so I excluded it for the sake of simplicity. I am not having trouble getting the expected output but I am having trouble getting typescript to recognize that the object has changed. I will update the function to provide more context around why this is happening.

Comment: Oh, okay... so the `console.log()` was showing the right output but you are not happy about the type coming out of the function.

Comment: You don't have to edit anything; I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, one problem with your original `Store<T>` is that a mapped type like `{[K in keyof T]: XXX}` is going to have the same keys as `T`.  So if `T` has a `modules` property, then so does `Store<T>`.  Another problem is that it isn't recursive... `ObjectInfer<T>` extracts the `modules` property of `T` if it has one, but it doesn't go down into those properties to do the same.

The actual implementation is going to have to be recursive and actually omit the `modules` key from what it outputs.  Here's a possible way to do it:

```
type Store<T> = T extends { modules: infer A }
  ? (StoreMap<Omit<T, "modules"> & A> extends infer S
      ? { [K in keyof S]: S[K] }
      : never)
  : T;
type StoreMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Store<T[K]> };
```

Before I explain this, let me explain a type which is equivalent, but produces much uglier output types:

```
type StoreUgly<T> = T extends { modules: infer A }
  ? StoreUglyMap<Omit<T, "modules"> & A>
  : T;
type StoreUglyMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: StoreUgly<T[K]> };
```

Here you see that what `StoreUgly` does is check if `T` has a `modules` property.  If not, it returns `T`.  Otherwise, it evalues `Omit<T, "modules"> & A` where `A` is the `modules` property.  `Omit<T, K>` is [defined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1466-L1469) in the standard library as a mapped type which removes `K` from the known keys of `T`.  So `Omit<{modules: 1, nodules: 2}, "modules">` is `{nodules: 2}`.  The intersection of `Omit<T, "modules"> & A` is the basic "pull the `modules` property up by one level" thing you were trying to do.

But of course we need to do it recursively, so we do `StoreUglyMap<>` on it, which just maps `StoreUgly` to each property.

The wrinkle is that the output is absolutely terrible... if you do `StoreUgly<typeof options>` you get a big mess.  Hence the `Store` version.  If you have an ugly object type `O` you can sometimes clean it up by writing `O extends infer X ? {[K in keyof X]: X[K]} : never`.  This just maps all the properties of `O` to themselves, but has the effect of more eagerly evaluating the properties instead of leaving them as bundles of intersections.

Let's make sure the output type is what you want:

```
type OutputType = Store<typeof options>;
/* 
type OutputType = {
    state: {};
    buildings: {
        state: {};
        school: {
            state: {};
        };
        cafe: {
            state: {};
        };
    };
} 
*/
```

Looks good to me!  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/PTAEHMEsDcFMDsBQBjA9vAzgF1KgDlpOhqALygDeioo2AhlrAFyUC+ANNaALaoAmAVwA2sDCyo0aAIwGQhfSPHBjKXSbSwNmbTupq9BIlRL00MyABapUQ8WtMat41vfUdXk5HQBm2kw8dGZw8aF1MwyQiXVgBuREQsAE88WFAAZSxUACdYAB4AFQA+MlB80FgAD0Z4PhIKHn5hURZFXyzQAEFQCIB+UAAKDOzYAFk6PFyAeW5ILAL2UAAiAyaMReKAMk7iyura0FbYdrSPPvqAbQBpA-hQAGtYRNRvdIBdFjSr1+6PFnhYOBZACUXBY+TiSRS6UyOTGEyKJQu10U90ez1K72hwwKX2KsXikNSkwEWDwJPyyVS5CGOVyhPR+EIxEKcWAACpQAlKaBiaTydzyP5An58eoZHIFEpjCFhc44gFzFYbHYAup6EE2PKHKKHF5fCrVWZNBqKDrwlrQnFWJy2cACdyabAAKrgISJArFchlXYIfb1FZGFrwNqdH40PqOl1uuFTGZzfILZaNIzrUBbDqFUGlCEOmHO12JGMIwWgK43VFPF75TGRgs4y6vPE5qG8slYCkpKOJEq1t10ykMghETAsxDszmEnkktsd-NuxH2dUii2gcXyRTKD55rsxgAKkGQd1yQrVxuXMoDzVUhrMlmstmvN9PTk1MrcK4Cer8b4cS7lP8tGUzW6RMl1TLYT0kRV7wNQ0-1fAJgPUL9YNVeDTQ-SIV1YUcXFtRAgA)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was after.

Comment: +1 for the concise explanation. I have moved the type conversion into the createStore method since I don't want users to write casts each time.

Comment: Yeah, the signature for `createStore` should be something like `createStore<T>(options: T): Store<T>` although you will likely have to do some type assertions inside your implementation

Comment: Nice tips . What about a specific type `type Prettify<T> = T extends infer Tbis ? { [K in keyof Tbis]: Tbis[K] } : never;`, making `type Store<T>` code easier to read: ` T extends { modules: infer A } ? Prettify<StoreMap<Omit<T, "modules"> & A>> : T` ?

Comment: Yes, you can break `Prettify<>` out into its own type alias, with the possible caveat that sometimes the compiler might display the name `Prettify<>` when you inspect the type.